# error for dependency and unable to remove with apt-get command

Tags: dependencies

after installing bundle `apt-get` command error me for dependency
and now i want to remove bundle but doesn't work
and any command for installing and error for dependencies
please help me
I unable to install other packages

```
apt-get remove bundle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bundle
```

what should i do?

Comment: I would advice switch over to latest release do not get stuck to 12.04,updates are important.

Comment: Just in the case of any other OS

Answer (score 1):

`bundle` is not installed on your system. Either your dependenciy problems prevented it from being installed, or you already removed it, or the package name is wrong.

I don't know of any `bundle` package (in Ubuntu 14.04). All I have is `bundler`:

```
Description-en: Manage Ruby application dependencies
Bundler manages a Ruby application's dependencies through its entire
life, across many machines, systematically and repeatably.

Bundler is most useful for developers of applications.
```

Did you misspell the name?

Comment: sorry you right it is bundler

Comment: now doesn't give me that error and now error me :

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 1.3.1) but 1.3.2ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: This is a different issue. You should open another question for that

Comment: sorry i'm new to linux